# jQuery click function to display text in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying display text in another div after a input button is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#excellent').click(function(){
    document.getElementById("voting").innerHTML = "Thank you for rating!";

    setTimeout(fade_out, 3000);

    function fade_out() {
      $("#voting").fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="excellent" type="image" src="smile.png" name="image" width="150" height="150">

<div id="footer">
  <p id="voting"></p>
</div>
```

The message for the innerHTML does appear and fades away, however when I click again on the image input, the text never appears again. How do I make it so that the text will always appear when clicked?

Comment: where is element with ID voting please include all relevant code to OP

Comment: Make sure you show the element after adding the text: `$('#voting').text('Thank you for rating!').show();`

Comment: also its better to move `function fade_out()` out of `click` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is hidden after `.fadeOut()` so you need to `.show()` the element after you have set the text.

You can also combine all that like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#excellent').click(function() {
        $("#voting").text("Thank you for rating!")
                    .show()
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Your `setTimeout` usage is correct, but in this simple case I would use the jQuery's [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) as it is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The element is "faded out", and you never show it again.  So you're just setting the text on an invisible element.

When you set the text, also make it visible:

```
document.getElementById("voting").innerHTML = "Thank you for rating!";
$("#voting").show();
```

or:

```
$("#voting").text("Thank you for rating!");
$("#voting").show();
```

or even:

```
$("#voting").text("Thank you for rating!").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `.show()` the `#voting` when using `fadeOut`. And you should use `clearTimeout` to prevent `fadeOut` starting on multiple clicks.

And why mixing plain js and jQuery? It would be easier to just use jQuery here, when you have it available already.

```
$(function() {
    var timeout;

    $('#excellent').click(function() {
        $("#voting").html("Thank you for rating!").show();

        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#voting").fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.fadeOut()` is set html element to display none , so it will never show until changing diplay property. Try something like this (my recommend)

```
<div id="footer">
    <p id="voting" style="display:none">Thank you for rating</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#excellent').click(function(){
   $("#voting").fadeIn();
   setTimeout(fade_out, 3000);
   function fade_out() {
        $("#voting").fadeOut();
   }
});
});
```